# Is it possible to change intersecting submanifolds of complementary dimension so that the homology class of their intersection won't change?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, intersection-theory, submanifold

Assume that $M$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $m$ and $A$, $B$ are its smooth submanifolds of dimensions $a$ and $b$ respectively and $a+b=m$. Is it true that one can find $A'$ and $B'$ of dimensions $a$ and $b$ so that $A'$ and $B'$ are transverse and
$$
H_0(A\cap B)=H_0(A'\cap B')? 
$$

Comment: What do you mean by "perturb"? It's not a well-defined word.

Comment: I changed the question. I just want to find new submanifolds A' and B' which are transverse and preserve the homology of intersection

Comment: So just to be clear, there is no relation between $A$ and $A'$ (resp. $B$ and $B'$), other than the fact that $H_0(A \cap B) = H_0(A' \cap B')$?

Comment: This is now a chameleon question, and I'm out of here. But as long as you're drifting from one question to another, you might want to at least specify whether the "new" submanifolds are in any way related to the old ones. If not, this second version can be simplified to "given a set $X$ (which used to the called $A \cap B$), are there transversely intersecting submanifolds whose intersection is $X$?"  Alternatively, you could pause for a moment and think hard about what you *actually* want to ask, and then ask that, so that you don't waste others' time.

Comment: Apart from demanding that the intersections have the same number of connected components and that dimA'=a and dimB'=b I don't want anything .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Consider $A$ as the graph of $y = x^2$ and $B$ as the graph of $y = -x^2$. Then any transverse intersection of the two has an even number of points (because $A' = x^2 + c$, $B' = B$, for $c > 0$, does). $A \cap B$ has a single point, the origin.

Comment: The OP didn't say what "perturb" mean. You could take $A' = \{ x = 0 \}$ and $B' = \{ y = 0 \}$... Without a definition of "perturb" it's not clear whether it's a counterexample or not.

Comment: I agree...but when folks talk about transversality, I tend to think that "perturb" means "displace each point slightly" (which only makes sense with a metric, I know) in a way that maintains the fact that they're embedded manifolds. As you say, though, this is definition-dependent. Then again, so are many of the questions we answer here. I'm sure OP will tell us if I didn't correctly understand what was being asked. :)

Comment: Alas, it appears that you were right, @NajibIdrissi. (As usual!)